# What am I missing?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I got this code from a WPF (very simple) application that illustrate my problem :

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<string> myColl = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    myColl.Add("1");
    myColl.Add("2");

    listBox1.ItemsSource = myColl;
}
```

This works !

But then I got this :

```
List<object> obj = new List<object>();
obj.Add(listBox1.ItemsSource);
obj[0] = myColl;
```

this doesn't work and the problem seems to be the listbox's ItemSource is "null" so in my List i got "null" and its dead, the object is "lost".
What so I have to change to "really" got my listbox's ItemSource in my List and not its value ?

(ps : I know this will be a noob question for a lot of you but I can't find what I'm missing, even if I feel that it's simple..)

EDIT : my List is with objects cause I'll have to handle different type of Collections (Lists, ObservableCollections and IEnumerable)

Comment: What will other elements of your list `obj` be used for? Applying `myColl` to other ListBoxes? Applying other collections to `listBox1`?

Comment: It will be other ObservableCollections and IEnumerables that will have to receive the "myColl" value !

Comment: This code smells really bad. I would suggest having another look at what you are trying to achieve - do you really need to make a list of itemssources? You already have an ObservableCollection of strings - can you not just add this to your list instead? But again - do you really want to be doing this? I suggest maybe starting another question stating what you are actually trying to achieve, so people can propose better solutions to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `obj.Add(listBox1.ItemsSource)` stores the current value of `listBox1.ItemsSource` - that's null, evidently - in `obj[0]` (or the next item in the list, if it's not empty.)

The line `obj[0] = myColl` then overwrites that null value with a reference to `myColl`. It doesn't affect `listBox1.ItemsSource` at all, because you've not stored any reference to `listBox1.ItemsSource` - only what was the value of that reference.

If you wanted to achieve what you're trying to do, you'd need to do something like the following:

```
List<Action<object>> obj = new List<Action<object>>();
obj.Add(o => listBox1.ItemsSource = o);
obj[0](myColl);
```

This is storing a list of actions, the first of which is "assign the given value to `listBox1.ItemsSource`", and then calling that action with the collection. (This should emulate what you expected your code above to do, but it's a bit rounabout - there's doubtless a simpler way to achieve whatever broader goal you have.)

Comment: Hum got the idea but for this to compile I had to do "obj.Add(o => listBox1.ItemsSource = o as IEnumerable);" but will be okay with ObservableCollections ?

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy - you could instead make `obj` a `List<Action<IEnumerable>>` which would be more type-safe. And ObservableCollection implements IEnumerable, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake here is assuming that the contents of `listBox1.ItemSource` is a pointer or other reference to your `ObservableCollection<string> myColl`. This is not the case.

`listBox1.ItemSource` is used for data binding `listBox1` to the contents of `myColl` (in your case), but as stated in MSDN:

> WPF never binds directly to a collection. If you specify a collection
>   as a binding source, WPF actually binds to the collection's default
>   view